# Fmap over a list of custom types?

Tags: haskell, functor

The below code won't compile:

```
data Outcome a = Fail | Pass a deriving (Show, Eq, Ord, Functor)

myList = [Pass 33, Pass 12, Fail, Pass 45]

main = do
   print $ fmap (+1) myList
```

I can't see why this doesn't work, as I've successfully applied the same approach to my binary tree of type 'data Tree a = Empty | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)'?

Answer (score 11):

The problem is that you are trying to add 1 to each element of the list `myList` which has type `Outcome Integer`. Try this instead:

```
fmap (fmap (+1)) myList
```

or to make it more clear:

```
map (fmap (+1)) myList
```

So the outer `fmap` applies to the list and the inner one applies to the `Outcome` functor. So, to each element of the list, we apply the function `fmap (+1)`, which in turn applies the function `(+1)` to the value inside the `Outcome`.

Comment: Sometimes writing `(fmap . fmap) (+1) myList`, `fmap2 = fmap . fmap` is handy too.

Comment: Sometimes, I like to call it `<$$>`.

Answer (score 6):

Lists are functors and you have an `[Outcome]` so you need to supply a function `Outcome -> b`. It looks like you want to apply `(+1)` to each `Outcome` within the list so you need to use:

```
fmap (\o -> fmap (+1) o) myList
```

or

```
fmap (fmap (+1)) myList
```